# Use a variable in SQL Where clause that contains commas

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, openquery

I have a table that is in SQL server 2008. The table has a field named CC_TERMID and it is a numeric field. I have data sitting on an oracle server in which I would like to find the current TermID's for the date we are in and I would like to use this as a variable against my SQL table. I am pretty sure my error is in the mismatch of data types, but I cannot figure out how to store the data for the variable.

Here is my variable I am creating using openquery to pull the data I want from Oracle:

```
    DECLARE @TERMS nvarchar(50)
    SET @TERMS = (SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(POWERSCHOOL,
    '
    SELECT TO_NUMBER(LISTAGG(ID, '','') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SCHOOLID))
    FROM TERMS
    WHERE SYSDATE + (SELECT FIRSTDAY - SYSDATE
                     FROM TERMS
                     WHERE ISYEARREC = 1 AND YEARID = (SELECT MAX(SUBSTR(TERMID, 1,2))
                                                       FROM CC) AND SCHOOLID = 51) BETWEEN FIRSTDAY AND LASTDAY AND SCHOOLID = 51
   '))
```

This returns data like 2700,2701,2703,2704

Now I want to use that variable in a query against my SQL table like this:

```
    SELECT TCH_EMAIL_ADDR, TCH_LAST_NAME, TCH_FIRST_NAME, CC_TERMID
    FROM ZPS_CCRAW
    WHERE CC_TERMID IN (@TERMS)
```

Of course I get the error: "Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric". I have tried to CAST/CONVERT CC_TERMID to a nvarchar like this:

```
    SELECT TCH_EMAIL_ADDR, TCH_LAST_NAME, TCH_FIRST_NAME, CC_TERMID
    FROM ZPS_CCRAW
    WHERE CAST(CC_TERMID AS NVARCHAR(50)) IN (@TERMS)
```

But I get no results returned. If I remove the @TERMS and I type in 2700,2701,2703,2704 then I will get data returned as expected.

I am nowhere near an expert when it comes to writing statements. I know enough to get me into trouble like this, but not enough to know how to get out of it. Can anyone help me achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: why do you use variable? just put your query in `in`

Comment: Ilya Bursov - The problem that I have is that the TermID will change according to the date. So in this case, Quarter 1 will be termID's 2700,2701,2703,2706. When Quarter 2 hits which will be towards the end of October, then I will need ID's 2700,2701,2703,2707. Each quarter will have a different set of ID's. When the next year comes everything now changes to 2800's. I am looking for a set it and forget it scripting so I don't have to always adjust the code manually.

Comment: How is your comment related to my question?

Comment: Sorry Ilya Bursov, I mis-read your question. You are correct also. I could have put my query into my in statement. This was one of those projects where I got so wrapped up into going down this path that I couldn't see anything else anymore.

Comment: @rockman20 experienced PowerSchool person here - you may be able to join off of the TERMS table to get the termids that you want, rather than your current strategy of changing the termids.  if this is of interest you can track down my contact info in my github profile and we could talk offline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to forgive me, I'm not good with Oracle, so it's possible the changes I made to your subquery don't quite work. But Basically the idea is, dont serialize the list. Just leave it as set data.

```
  DECLARE @TERMS table (Id int)

  insert into @TERMS (Id)
  SELECT ID FROM OPENQUERY
  (
      POWERSCHOOL,
      'SELECT DISTINCT ID 
       FROM TERMS
       WHERE SYSDATE + (SELECT FIRSTDAY - SYSDATE
                        FROM TERMS
                        WHERE ISYEARREC = 1 AND YEARID = (SELECT MAX(SUBSTR(TERMID, 1,2))
                                                          FROM CC) AND SCHOOLID = 51) BETWEEN FIRSTDAY AND LASTDAY AND SCHOOLID = 51'
  )
```

Then change your subsequent query to something like this:

```
 SELECT TCH_EMAIL_ADDR, TCH_LAST_NAME, TCH_FIRST_NAME, CC_TERMID
 FROM ZPS_CCRAW
 WHERE CC_TERMID IN (select Id @TERMS)
```

or

```
 SELECT TCH_EMAIL_ADDR, TCH_LAST_NAME, TCH_FIRST_NAME, CC_TERMID
 FROM ZPS_CCRAW a
 INNER JOIN @TERMS b
      on a.CC_TERMID = b.Id
```

Note, you could do the same directly from OPENQUERY rather than dumping them in a table variable if you prefer.

What's basically happening is you have a table that looks like...

```
... CC_TERMID
... 2700
... 2701
... 2703
... 2704
```

...and you're currently saying "Give me all the rows where CC_TERMID equals the string-literal `"2700,2701,2703,2704"`

Comment: My answer relates to SQL Server. The content of his remote query is written in PL/SQL (AKA Oracle), which he mentioned in, just like, the second line of his post. That's the portion I don't know the syntax for. However I thought I made that pretty clear. As for the `@...` things, those are variable declarations, and the OP even has them himself.

Comment: Thank you Xedni! I didn't realize I could declare a table as a variable. The only thing I had to change was the (select Id @TERMS) to (select id FROM @TERMS) Otherwise this was a perfect answer. I also appreciate that I have learned that I can declare a table as a variable.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Your Oracle query is fine.  It's the way SQL Server is interpreting the statement.  It's been a while since I've worked with SQL Server but I don't think you can use a variable in this way.  I would have used a dynamic query so the @terms would be interpreted as a list of values instead of as a string.

Comment: The main problem with doing this in DSQL is that it's not injection proof.

Comment: The risk of injection is minimal since your variable is created from a select statement not a user interface field.  The select statement is returning a list of numbers which would be difficult to inject.